# Can we use Cardano's method if the coefficients of the equation is not real?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, cubics

Can we use Cardano's method if the coefficients of the equation is not real?

If yes, is it done the same way? If no, how can we solve such equations.

Comment: Yes, provided you know how to take the square root and cube root of a complex number.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as using the quadratic formula to solve quadratics with nonreal coefficients. Once you understand where the formula/method comes from, you can see what impediments, if any, there are to using it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Actually, Cardano's formula works on any field whose characteristic is neither $2$ nor $3$ and on which every number has a square root and a cube root.

Here is an example (over $\mathbb C$). Consider the equation$$x^3-13ix-15+15i=0.\tag1$$Then$$\frac{(-15+15i)^2}4+\frac{(-13i)^3}{27}=-\frac{1\,681}{54}i=\left(\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}-\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}i\right)^2.$$Now, consider the numbers$$-\frac{-15+15i}2+\left(\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}-\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}i\right)\tag2$$and$$-\frac{-15+15i}2-\left(\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}-\frac{41}{6\sqrt3}i\right).\tag3$$It turns out that a cube root of $(2)$ is$$1+\frac{5\sqrt3}6i+\left(\frac12-\frac{2\sqrt3}3\right)i\tag4$$and that a cube root of $(3)$ is$$1-\frac{5\sqrt3}6i+\left(\frac12+\frac{2\sqrt3}3\right)i;\tag5$$besides, the product of these cube roots is $\frac{13i}3$. So, by Cardano's formula, $(4)+(5)$ should be a root of $(1)$. And it is: $(4)+(5)=2+i$ and you can check that $2+i$ is indeed a root of $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. When I say $x = (a+c)+(b+d)i$ instead of $x = a+b$, I find that the coefficient of the linear term always needs to be a complex number. So that means $x$ in terms of imaginary numbers makes the coefficient complex, too. But it is obvious that we have complex roots but real coefficients in most cases. Why do I find the coefficient of the linear term equal a complex number. I do the same operations as we do with the algebraic identity in Cardano's method, which is $(a+b)^3 = a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea about what you are saying.

Comment: Hope this is clear and makes sense. https://prnt.sc/qljm5k

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: I hope this is okay. https://ibb.co/prJC8nb

Comment: That is just a sequence of formulas, without words. I have added an example to my answer.